# Centos 8 Suspend/Sleep on inactivity

Tags: wake-on-lan, suspend, centos-8

I have setup a Centos 8 workstation and have not found any way to get it to sleep even after lots of googling around.

How do I get it to sleep on inactivity, and get it to Wake-On-Lan?

Comment: Did you check this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511993/not-able-to-hibernate-or-suspend-centos-system